# A word to describe staff member that is treated well by other colleagues

Tags: word-choice

I am writing an essay that need a word describing an employee who is treated well by most of his/her colleagues? Or is there any common phrase for that? Please, give me some suggestions.

Comment: Please don't use all caps for titles. It's unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe just "favorite"? Or "popular"?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas: esteemed, respected, well-liked, well-favored. But "treated well" might be more accurate than any of these.

Other terms that mean treated well but to an excessive degree are "pampered", or "fawned over".

Comment: Just to expand on Chad's answer...The second set of terms (pampered, fawned over) would be considered negative by the co-workers.  I would use "respected" or "well-liked."  "Well-favored" sounds a little like old English to me.  If you want to be very formal in your writing, "esteemed" is an excellent word.  However, it sounds like you want an every-day, common word that native English speakers would use.  In this case, I might even combine two of the words in one sentence...He was respected and well-liked among all his colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support <3. I have looked up all of your suggestions in Oxford Dictionary and decided to use "esteemed". It has the closest meaning to my context. Thanks again ^^